# Target output browser for webapplication in monodevelop

Tags: browser, monodevelop

It must be a trivial option hidden somewhere.
I have a web application in monodevelop. When I run it (f5) it starts in chromium (chrome for linux). I want to change this to firefox or to nothing (don't start a browser, I can reload the page myself).
Can anyone tell me how I change this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MonoDevelop uses your default browser, according to your GNOME preferences (on Linux). It's not possible to change this without than changing your default or modifying the MD source code.